# How to set column value default to configured in database using hibernate XML mapping?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi I am looking for solution to set xml mapping to set default column value to as configured in DB.

e.g
Table
column UPDATE_BY_DATE, UPDATE_BY_USER
type timestamp, varchar
default SYSDATE, USER

XML Mapping

```
<property name="updatedByTime" column="UPDATE_BY_DATE" not-null="true" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false"/>
<property name="updatedByUser" column="UPDATE_BY_USER" length="20" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

this works for inserting new record but not working when updating entity.
I want to make it working for update too.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no default for update in db... you can make do with triggers or much more easily with @PreUpdate annotation on the entity

example

```
@Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entityCreation;

    @Column()
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entityUpdate;

    @PreUpdate
    public void setLastUpdate() {
        entityUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

every time an entity is updated you set it's date to currentMillis

Comment: Is there any way to configure @PreUpdate in XML?

Comment: Never used xml for this... try look up interceptor or event listener, be careful that event config changed from hibernate 3 to 4 so check version